# How to scroll two view simultaneously in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have bar chart view where i can scroll the bars.And I have tableview such that when im scrolling the barchart simultaneously tableview should scroll.Just give idea to do with touch or gesture methods.

Answer (score 0):

Refer `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` method in [*UITableView*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.

I guess this method will help you for your requirement which you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

when you are scrolling the bar, take the event and call this method:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:indexPath.section] 
         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
```